# What script does SSMS run when asking for the 'Effective' items on the 'Permissions' screen for a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, ssms, windows-users

Suppose that I want to see who has permissions on a table in my database. In my ignorance, I trust the GUI to give me all of the answers. I therefore open up the database in SSMS and navigate to the table I desire. I right-click on it and go to "Properties". From here, I navigate to "Permissions". I see that this requires me to specify a user, so I specify a Windows user. Let's call them `FooCorp\x12345`. On the 'Explicit' menu, I see that they have no permissions at all. I therefore click on the 'Effective' menu and I get this error.

> Could not obtain information about windows NT group/user 'FooCorp\x12345', error code 0x5

I really don't care about fixing this error. Instead, I want to know this: **What procedure, script, or other object was used by SSMS to (fail to) fetch the 'Effective' permissions?**

Comment: Note: There are many questions with the same error message. They refer to connecting to the database. This is not my issue. I am asking about a specific menu.

Comment: You could boot up profiler and see what query it runs.

Comment: Without the GUI, I typically use impersonation to determine effective permissions. Speculatively, that's probably what it's doing as well. What happens if you do `execute as user = 'FooCorp\x12345'; select * from sys.fn_my_permissions('yourTable', 'object'); revert;` I'd run those one statement at a time. Speculatively, I think you may not have impersonate permissions on that user.

Comment: @BenThul I'm beginning to think the same, but I'm sure that I'm a SysAdmin and a dbowner.

Comment: *"The user or login name specified in EXECUTE AS <context_specification> must exist as a principal in sys.database_principals or sys.server_principals, respectively, or the EXECUTE AS statement fails."* so if the Windows user does not even have CONNECT permissions it's not going to work.

Comment: @Charlieface They're listed in both of those.

Comment: @ThomA Done as you suggested. See answer.

Comment: @Charlieface Done as you suggested. See answer.

Comment: @Charlieface I have no reason to believe that they're orphaned. I can find a login with the same name as the user and I know that this user has wrote to the relevant table in the past.

Comment: What happens if you run the below script yourself in SSMS?

Comment: @Charlieface Exactly the same error as in the question.

Comment: Hmm 0x5 is a Windows error code Access Denied, I'm guessing the user is a domain user and SQL Server is running under a local service account (rather than a domain gMSA account)? Might explain the issue. Or possibly the machine it's on is not domain-joined at all?

Comment: @Charlieface I believe your first guess is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments correctly suggested checking the SQL Server Profiler. It reports that the script is:

```sql
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'FooCorp\x12345';
SELECT
    permission_name AS [Permission]
    ,subentity_name as [Column]
FROM fn_my_permissions(N'[dbo].[tblTest]', N'OBJECT')
ORDER BY permission_name, subentity_name;
REVERT;
```